# Botman laravel REST API setup

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

Im new to Botman.

I try to implement a simple function to test how it works, but I keep getting empty response, it look like botman do not hears my message.

I installed botman without studio since, I'm trying to keep things simple. I also installed a webdriver as it says in documentation.

In my project I use JWT as an authentification, so i created a protected route like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['assign.guard:user', 'jwt.auth']], function () {

    Route::post(
        '/',
        'UserBotManController@startConversation'
    )->name('botman.user.start');

});
```

The controller looks like this:

```
<?php


namespace Project\UI\Api\Controllers\User\Botman;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;

class UserBotManController extends Controller
{
    public function startConversation()
    {
        $config = [];

        DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class);

        $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

        $botman->hears('hello', function (BotMan $bot) {
            $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
        });

        $botman->listen();
    }
}
```

No when I send a request to this route a get empty response:
[image]

Looks like botman can't hear my message...

I try to looked inside with: `dd($botman->getDriver());`

And I see that the content has all the data:
[image]

Can any one help me to understand, how I can make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so finally I found a solution. I have checked what request it sends from https://botman.io website and it is Form Data, not JSON.

[image]

`diver` field must be set to `web`!

Hope it will help someone.